# Creating a list of instances of derivatives from a generic abstract class

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

Consider this base class:

```
public abstract class TestGenericList<T> {

    public TestGenericList() {
    }

    protected abstract void doSomething();
}
```

Now, two derived classes:

```
public class DerivedA extends TestGenericList<DerivedA> {

    @Override
    protected void doSomething() {
        //
    }
}
public class DerivedB extends TestGenericList<DerivedB> {

    @Override
    protected void doSomething() {
        //
    }
}
```

Application class:

```
public class TestListMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DerivedA dA = new DerivedA();
        DerivedB dB = new DerivedB();

        List<TestGenericList> genericList = new ArrayList<TestGenericList>();
        genericList.add(dA);
        genericList.add(dB);
    }
}
```

The line with the list creation gives this warning:

```
TestGenericList is a raw type. References to generic type TestGenericList<T> should be parameterized
```

How can I generate a list of derivatives of a generic abstract base class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type information will get lost if you add both types to the list. Thus you will only know that the list contains `TestGenericList` objects of an unkown type `<?>`.

```
List<TestGenericList<?>> genericList = new ArrayList<TestGenericList<?>>();
```

This might be sufficient in your case, but you should always think about if this is what you want. Why did you introduce a type information when it gets lost later? There are cases when it makes sense. E.g. take a look at [`Collections.disjoint(Collection<?> c1, Collection<?> c2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29).

Answer (score 2):

`TestGenericList<T>` is a generic type declaration, and you are using this as raw type. Here you should    use `TestGenericList<DerivedA>` or `TestGenericList<?>`in order to remove warning.